# swapping nodes in doubly linked list

Tags: c#

Trying to swap the second and third nodes from a doubly linked list in c# with the following method:-

```
public static void swapNodes(List dblLinkList)
{
    Node tempnodeTwo = dblLinkList.firstNode.next;          //node two in list
    Node tempnodeThree = dblLinkList.firstNode.next.next;   //node three in list

    Node tempnodeFive = tempnodeTwo.previous;
    Node tempnodeSix = tempnodeThree.next;

    tempnodeThree.previous = tempnodeFive;
    tempnodeThree.next = tempnodeThree;
    tempnodeTwo.previous = tempnodeTwo;
    tempnodeTwo.next = tempnodeSix;
}
```

The following shows the output: The first is the original list and the second is the result of the method.

```
N:19:16 19:16:9 16:9:15 9:15:15 15:15:N
N:19:16 16:16:15 9:15:15 15:15:N
```

Where am I going wrong?? I have already studied previous questions about this topic which gave me the idea for the code but now stuck!

Answer (score 1):

well here in these lines

```
  tempnodeThree.next = tempnodeThree;
  tempnodeTwo.previous = tempnodeTwo;
```

you are setting the next of a node to itself and the previous of another to itself.

don't you mean

```
  tempnodeThree.next = tempnodeTwo;
  tempnodeTwo.previous = tempnodeThree;
```

I think you would have an easier time if you used better names.

I also would not implement this function like this -- I'd make the function suit it's name like this:

```
public static void swapNodes(Node a, Node b)
{
  if (a == null) return;
  if (b == null) return;

  Node afterA = a.next;
  Node beforeA = a.previous;

  a.previous = b.previous;
  if (b.previous != null) b.previous.next = a;
  a.next = b.next;
  if (b.next != null) b.next.previous = a;

  b.next = afterA;
  if (afterA != null) afterA.previous = b;
  b.previous = beforeA;
  if (beforeA != null) beforeA.next = b;
}

// call it like this
swapNodes(dblLinkList.firstNode.next, dblLinkList.firstNode.next.next);
```

Comment: Recommendations for "better names" would make this a more complete answer.

Comment: @Xtros -- really?  I'd think having the "number" in the names be the same as the order in the list is the most obvious one (tempnodeFive -> tempnodeOne and tempnodeSix -> tempnodeFour) but the details of that are not my point.  Clearly these names are confusing and by observation you can see when names are not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you assume `tempnodeThree` is the third and `tempnodeTwo` is the second node 
of the linked list regardless of the changes you make but this is not the case.

After the initializations what you get is:

tempnodeFive <--> tempnodeTwo <--> tempnodeThree <--> tempnodeSix

And you need is:

tempnodeFive <--> tempnodeThree <--> tempnodeTwo  <--> tempnodeSix

So what you have to change from left to right are:

`tempNodeFive.next`, `tempNodeTwo.previous`, `tempNodeTwo.next`, `tempNodeThree.previous`, `tempNodeThree.next`, `tempNodeSix.previous`

Let's go over them following the 2nd linked list representation:

```
tempNodeFive.next = tempNodeThree;
tempNodeTwo.previous = tempnodeThree;
tempNodeTwo.next = tempnodeSix;
tempNodeThree.previous = tempnodeFive;
tempNodeThree.next = tempnodeTwo;
tempNodeSix.previous = tempnodeTwo;
```

These six lines are what you need.

PS: You can reconsider variable names for a readable and maintainable code, esp. tempNodeFive and tempnodeSix because five and six does not make any sense as an index and it arises confusion while reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's **c#**? Looks like java. C# has `LinkedListNode<T>` class, not `Node`. And `LinkedListNode<T>` has `Next` and `Previous` properties. With **capitals**. And they are **read only**.

Any way c# implementation looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LinkedListSwap
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new LinkedList<string>(new[] { "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th" });
            Console.WriteLine(list.ToDisplayString());
            list.Swap(2, 3);
            Console.WriteLine(list.ToDisplayString());
        }
    }

    static class LinkedListExtensions
    {
        public static void Swap<T>(this LinkedList<T> list, int firstIndex, int secondIndex)
        {
            if (firstIndex < 1 || firstIndex > list.Count)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Index out of range: {nameof(firstIndex)}");

            if (secondIndex < 1 || secondIndex > list.Count)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Index out of range: {nameof(secondIndex)}");

            if (firstIndex == secondIndex)
                return;

            if (firstIndex > secondIndex)
                (firstIndex, secondIndex) = (secondIndex, firstIndex);

            int i = 0;

            var leftNode = list.First;
            while (++i < firstIndex)
                leftNode = leftNode.Next;

            var rightNode = leftNode.Next;
            while (++i < secondIndex)
                rightNode = rightNode.Next;

            list.Replace(leftNode, rightNode);
            list.Replace(rightNode, leftNode);
        }

        public static void Replace<T>(this LinkedList<T> list, LinkedListNode<T> oldNode, LinkedListNode<T> newNode)
        {
            list.AddAfter(oldNode, new LinkedListNode<T>(newNode.Value));
            list.Remove(oldNode);
        }

        public static string ToDisplayString<T>(this LinkedList<T> list) => string.Join(" ", list);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 7th
1st 3rd 2nd 4th 5th 6th 7th
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go.

Comment: But this is not a linked list; it's an array. ;-)